# A non-linear second order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general solution to the following PDE:

$$ \left(\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}-1\right)
   \left(\frac {\partial f} {\partial y}-1\right)
  +\frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial x \partial y}f =0$$

The problem came up in a certain mechanism design model trying to analyse climate treaties. A general solution to the above PDE would enable me to compute an optimal treaty within the model.

Comment: For any function $\phi$, $x+\phi(y)$ and $y+\phi(x)$ are  solutions.